# I want the first 3 cells in a row to be filled with a certain color only if the rest of the row is blank. Is there an easier way?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-workspace

```
=AND(ISBLANK(D2:D98), ISBLANK(E2:E98), ISBLANK(F2:F98), ISBLANK(G2:G98), ISBLANK(H2:H98), ISBLANK(I2:I98), ISBLANK(J2:J98), ISBLANK(K2:K98), ISBLANK(L2:L98), ISBLANK(M2:M98), ISBLANK(N2:N98))
```

This is what I have for my custom formula -- and it works. It's just very time consuming to implement and edit. Is there a better way?

Using Google Sheets, but can and would switch to Excel 2013 (what is available to me at work) if it would make a difference.

Comment: In Excel you could use conditional formatting with a simpler formula. But your formula refers to columns, and your question has to do with rows. So it is not clear to me what you are really doing.  Care to clarify?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Did you get this sorted out, @Dave?

Answer (score 2):

with a range of A2:C,

```
=AND(COUNTA($A2:$C2)>=1,COUNTA($D2:$N2)=0)
```

This will check for anything in the first three columns and also if D:N on the same row is blank.